# Relative import in python2.6.5

Tags: python

Relative import not working properly in python2.6.5 getting "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package".

I am having all those `__init__.py` in proper place.

Comment: (1) It's `__init__.py`, make sure you have that right. (2) Are you sure all of your `__init__` files are in the right place? Please post a list of your directory structure so we can help point out errors.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the problem is unless you give us an overview of your directory structure and the offending code.

Comment: You should probably show your import statements and your directory structure in order to receive help...

Comment: PythonEvent
--main.py
--__init__.py
DBConnector
 -- __init__.py
 -- connector.py
service
 -- __init__.py
 -- myservice.py

Now in myservice.py i have a line like 
from ..DBConnector.connector  import DBUpdate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen that error before when running a script that is actually *inside* a package.  To the interpreter, it appears as though the package is not a package.

Try taking the script into another directory, putting your package inside your `pythonpath`, and import absolutely.  Then, relative imports inside your package will work.  NOTE: you can STILL not relatively import inside the end script - the easiest thing to do in this case is to make a "wrapper" script, that simply calls some entry point in your package.

You can go even further here by using `setuptools` to create a [`setup.py`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools) for your package, to make it distributable.  Then, as a part of that, [entry points](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#automatic-script-creation) would allow you to autogenerate scripts that called your package's code.

**EDIT**:

From your comment, it appears as though I wasn't quite clear.  I'm not 100% sure of your directory structure because your comment above wasn't formatted, but I took it to be like this:

```
PythonEvent/
    main.py
    __init__.py
    DBConnector/
        __init__.py
        connector.py
    service/
        __init__.py
        myservice.py
```

When in `myservice.py` you have the line `from ..DBConnector.connector import DBUpdate`, the interpreter tries to import it relatively, **UNLESS** you are running `myservice.py` directly.  This is what it appears you are doing.

Try making another dummy script outside of `PythonEvent/` that is simply as follows:

```
from PythonEvent.service import myservice

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myservice.main() # or whatever the entry point is called in myservice.
```

Then, set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to point to the parent directory of `PythonEvent/` (or move `PythonEvent/` to your site-packages).

Answer (score 0):

```
main.py
setup.py
Main Package/ ->
    __init__.py
    subpackage_a/ ->
       __init__.py
       module_a.py
    subpackage_b/ ->
       __init__.py
       module_b.py
```

i)

```
    1.You run python main.py
    2.main.py does: import app.package_a.module_a
    3.module_a.py does import app.package_b.module_b
```

ii)

```
    Alternatively 2 or 3 could use: from app.package_a import module_a
```

> That will work as long as you have app in your PYTHONPATH. main.py could be anywhere then.

So you write a setup.py to copy (install) the whole app package and subpackages to the target system's python folders, and main.py to target system's script folders.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1083169